# TTL for state in ProcessWindowFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, ttl

I would like to set the TTL of the state in a processwindowfunction. This state is shared across windows. This TTL needs to be based on an attribute in the event itself. So I cannot calculate the TTL in the state descriptor. Also, onTimer function is not supported in processwindowfunction.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the time-to-live must be computed as a function of the event itself, then you can't use the state TTL mechanism.

The only alternative is to use timers with a `KeyedProcessFunction`, rather than using the window API. There's an example in the flink documentation: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/learn-flink/event_driven.html#example

Comment: Thanks David. Is there any good example of implementing one's own tumbling window using KeyedProcessFunction? I would like to imitate processing a window of a given duration and emitting a result for that time period.

Comment: Yes, see the example in the tutorials in the flink docs: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/learn-flink/event_driven.html#example